# Can you redirect a 404 to a WordPress page and still show response code 404?

Tags: 404-error

As the title says, I would love to know if its possible to redirect to a WordPress page when an url is not found, but show a 404 response code on that page?

I've been playing around yesterday with header status 404 and location to a certain page in my 404.php, but this would always show a 200 response code.

I was wondering if I could do this without modifying the 404.php (only a redirect) and without a plugin.

Is there a tutorial or anything I can follow somewhere? I wasn't able to find this.
Thanks in advance!

I tried all sorts of things:

```
<?php
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
header("Location: FULLURL / RELATIVEURL");
get_header(); ?>
```

But also these as response codes:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
http_response_code(404);
status_header(404);
```

I also tried placing the 404 under the redirect:

```
header("Location: FULLURL / RELATIVEURL");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

- I also tried placing the 404 error codes on the page itself in a custom HTML block
- I even tried to iframe the page into the 404, but this wasn't the way to go either!

Comment: Is your ultimate goal here just to be able to edit the 404 page? Or is the redirect important?

Comment: Ha Sorry Jacob for my late answer, but yes the redirect is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a htaccess rule?

```
ErrorDocument 404 the-404-page-permalink
```

(changing the page to the actual URL of the desired page)

Or, does your theme have a 404.php page?  If so, create a child theme (so you don't change the theme files which will get overwritten with a theme update) and create your own 404.php in your child theme.

Comment: A Custom 404.php does not give me (as a newbie) enough options to create the 404 in the same style as my other webpages. For example, I'd love to have a banner, the normal footer etc.

Comment: Then create your own custom 404 type Page on your site. Use that page's URL in the htaccess command. There are also '404' plugins that you can use.

Comment: That might be the solution yeah, thanks!

Comment: It's always polite to 'checkmark' an answer that works for you. Helps others learn things too. Helps your 'reputation' here (and mine).